Как в Unity при scroll сделать чтобы координаты в которые нужно перетащить элемент из scroll не сдвигались наверх
Есть список блоков которые хранятся в scrollView, данные блоки нужно перетаскивать в указанные им места (принцип магазина). На тех местах стоят ячейки которые считывают координаты для помещения блока туда.
Проблема заключается в том, что при прокрутке scroll это ячейки, которые указывают место назначения блока, съезжают на верх, как это исправить(если же не прокручивать, то конечно же все нормально)?
